# calling interface function that is not implemented in java

Tags: java

I am having trouble understanding a code that is using an interface function but i don't seem to find the implementation for it. Is it possible to call an unimplemented interface function? The code is below,
The class that calls the unimplemented function combineResults:

```
public final class Parallel { 
 public static <T> T For(int start, int end, 
   ParallelForDelegate<T> delegate, T input) { 
  T res = null; 
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
   res = delegate.combineResults(res, delegate.delegate(i, input)); 
  } 
  return res; 
 } 
 }
```

The interface:

```
public  interface  ParallelForDelegate<T> { 
 public  T delegate(int i, T input); 

 public  T combineResults(T result1, T result2); 
}
```

Reference:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=SecugenPlugin-master/src/sourceafis/simple/Fingerprint.java#

Comment: If you are using IDE then it will very easily find implementation ot just print delegate.getClass() you will get your answer.

Comment: "I don't seem to find the implementation for it". Have you looked at classes that implement `ParallelForDelegate`?

Comment: Well at runtime, `delegate` is passed into the method which will implement the interface.

Comment: Hava a look at the `delegate ` which passed into when call the method of `For ` in class `Parallel `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be an implementation somewhere, but sometimes you can have a hard time finding it, because of various factories, dependecy injections, 'on-the-fly' building, ... mecanisms

On complex APIs like Hibernate, it can be tedious. However, the interface is supposed to give you enough details on its usage so you don't actually **have** to know how it's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In the  method

> public static  T For(int start, int end,     ParallelForDelegate
>   delegate, T input)

of Parallel class you are taking ParallelForDelegate as a reference, so, you can call methods of ParallelForDelegate Interface. 
the key thing is you have to pass implementation class object of ParallelForDelegate interface when you call For (-,-,-,-) method. So,

> delegate.combineResults(res, delegate.delegate(i, input));

calls, that implementation class method at runtime.